# macOS Big Sur can format drive but can't mount it

Tags: macos, usb, big-sur, mount, disk-format

I have a USB stick and can format the stick, but when I try to mount it, the following error occurs:

[image: Screenshot of an error message in German that reads 'Mounting of 'Ohne Titel' has failed']

The error is in German, it means "Mounting of "Ohne Titel" has failed. (com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter -Error -119930873)"

I can't find any solutions online and don't know what to do.

There is no data on this stick so I can easily format it.

Comment: I saw similar errors when trying to work on a drive that turned out broken. Strangely format worked and even some operations on  the drive. No warnings or errors from the mac - the only sign on was the operations were abysmally slow - and would even crash my mac every now and then. Do you have another machine at hand to confirm the drive is really functional?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of "googling" I can see the problem occurs to other people too.

Try to follow the guide proposed below before you go a step further.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252126476

Just to reason a bit more on the problem: have you modified the settings of the stick via software or hardware ( e.g. moving an unlock button)?
This guys solved with a software different from Disk Utility, but I don't think it is necessary.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252081600

Comment: I am sorry, but none of these solutions work for me.

Comment: The first thing you can do is update the OS to the latest version. Then, if the problem still occurs, try to go on Disk Utility.
Select View->Show All Devices.
Then select the external device named "Ohne Titel" and click erase.
Insert the following parameters:

Name:Ohne Titel
Format:APFS (or HFS/HFS+ if APFS not available)
Scheme: GUID Partition Map

Try to umount and mount the usb-stick again.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar error on a brand new MBP and brand new USB stick where the newly formatted drive (fat32) would not auto mount. I had to mount the usb drive manually following the instructions below:

- create a volume dir: `sudo mkdir /Volumes/usb`
- find the disk where the usb is listed (in my case it was under `/dev/disk2`: `diskutil list`
- mount the volume: `sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk2 /Volumes/usb`